# American vs American-based

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What is the difference between saying someone is "**an American artist**" and someone is "**an American-based artist**"? I think the latter is used when the artist is an American artist but he is currently known working in another country or internationally. Am I right?

Comment: I THINK you've got it backwards, but could make a better guess if you provided a specific example.

Comment: A person born and raised in America, living in Paris without a home or phone number in america would NOT be an american-based-artist ... they might appear on French-based-artist lists. While based in France the American Artist could paint American-based-art of the grand canyon despite being a american french-based artist.

Comment: They are not contrasting terms

Answer (score 1):

"**American Artist**" is fairly clear as it suggestions the nationality of the artist... nationality generally means "at birth" (we could quibble about a child born abroad to american parents)

There might be some controversy whether "america" included Canada, Mexico, Brazil etc ... but in most English language publications America might be fairly anticipated to mean "of the united states'

David Beckham (futbol) wouldn't be called an "American Professional Athlete" even when he was a star on a US team.  Emma Watson isn't an "american actress" even though she stars in american made productions ... Star in american films yes, American Actress ?.. not really.  American Movie Star  - well that is tougher .. depending on context and where you might put hyphens.

**American-based-artist** could be trickier but mostly because of assumptions one might make without a lack of context.

"based" is most commonly used as a designation of where a international business has it headquarters.  It can also be used for an individual who works internationally but returns to america between jobs.

Apple and Google and Coca Cola can alternatively be called American Companies or American-based companies. Sometimes though, companies which primarily do business in the USA might still keep their headquarters in some foreign country for tax purposes etc.

Now, it might get a bit trickier with "American-Based-Artist" as artists don't typically have "headquarters"... however anyone who frequently works abroad but keeps a primary business address and primary home somewhere is 'based' where that business address is.

The tricky part is that it's most common to assume that a person will operate out of their country of origin unless specified... so that specification which would run counter to that norm suggests that it is a special case.
... so a person might leap to the conclusion that they must be a foreign national because you wouldn't bother otherwise.

Another trip up could be the confusion about subject matter, although it really shouldn't be.

A french novelist could write "american-based-novels" while living in London ... but that would not make him a "american-based-novelist" unless he lived in america.

It is highly unlikely that you would call an american artist an american based artist... but you could.  If a foreign company were looking for graphic artists they could very well have a list of "american based artists" which included both american artists living in america and British artists living in america.

- American Artist - an artist of American nationality
- American-based-artist  an artist of Any nationality doing business from america

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete response. Therefore, if I want to talk about a German (born in Germany) artist who is generally working in America should I say "a German artist based in America" and "An American-based artist born in Germany"?

Comment: Yes either of those would be clear and mean the same thing. The first though is probably easier to understand unless you were already on the subject of  "where artists were based"

Answer (score -2):

American-based means a non-America currently working in America.

Comment: While one might leap to this conclusion in the absence of other context it is not strictly true.  If one were sitting in New Zealand and making a list of artists you might commission for a project "American based artists" you would include both Americans and foreign nationals living in the US on that list.